# Mapping View and Table in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have a table and primary key is DocId. And I have a view which also have a docId. And the entity and view is mapped in the below fashion.

How can I map ClaimInferredValues  in Claim Entity? So Claim can bring all inferred vales for that docId

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLAIM")
public class Claim  {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "DOC_ID")
  private String docId;
  
  ...
  .....
  }
  
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = "V_CLAIM_INFERRED_VALUES")
public class ClaimInferredValues {

@EmbeddedId ClaimInferredValuesId ClaimInferredValuesId;
....
....
}


@Embeddable
public class ClaimInferredValuesId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "inferredInfoKey")
  private String inferredInfoKey;

  @Column(name = "inferredInfoValue")
  private String inferredInfoValue;

  @Column(name = "DocId")
  private String docId;
  
  ------
  ---
  
  
  }
```

Comment: You could do it as a oneToMany relation from Claim, but it would be against the philosophy of JPA, to model entities that repeat the DDL from the database. I understand that the FK does not exist in the DB, it is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do that. You can just query the data like this:

```
SELECT c, v
FROM Claim c
JOIN ClaimInferredValues v ON v.ClaimInferredValuesId.docId = c.docId
```